# Post data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using sortable to sort a list. Then once the user clicks the Submit button I want it to post the data to another php page. I currently can get it to display an alert with the data I want posted but can't get the JavaScript post right.

This is the submit button.

```
<input type='submit' value='Submit' onclick='saveOrder();'/>
```

This is the JavaScript part that creates an alert.

```
function saveOrder() 
{
    var wordOrder = $( "#sortable" ).sortable('toArray').toString();
    alert(wordOrder);          
}
```

This outputs `a,b,c,d,e` in an alert box. I want this posted instead of showing an alert.

What I would like to do is post this data so I can loop through it on another PHP page.

```
foreach( $_POST as $stuff ) 
{                
    echo $stuff;
}
```

Comment: I'd take a look to jQuery in general for your client side and to jQuery ajax methods in particular: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: You need ajax. Did you try/google ajax? -> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via ajax: -> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
function saveOrder() {
    var wordOrder = $( "#sortable" ).sortable('toArray').toString();
    $.post( "your/file.php", {wordOrder: wordOrder}, function( data ) {
      //Do nothing
    });
    //$.post("your/file.php", {wordOrder: wordOrder});
}
```

in PHP, you can:

```
echo $_POST['wordOrder'];
```

Comment: Thanks this is perfect. Is it possible that instead of diaplaying the alert it loads the file that the data has just been posted to?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstanding. What I meant is don't show any alert but load "your/file.php"

Comment: what do you mean? change the button type to submit

Comment: When you click the button nothing happens. No page load nothing

Comment: is your input button type submit?

Comment: Yes the button type is submit

Comment: Then you need event.preventDefault() at the form submit level.